# javascript innerHTML transition

Tags: javascript

So, i am new to javaScript or programming what so ever. I have been given a task, to create a simple JS calculator. It seemed easy but I've encountered an error at the beginning of my challenge. 
I have 1-9 number buttons with span class = nButton, i have a div with class = Screen but pressing on any nKey doesn't work.
what am i doing wrong here?

```
var nKeys = document.getElementsByClassName('nButton');
var display = document.getElementsByClassName('Screen');


for (var i = 0; i < nKeys.length; i++) {
    nKeys[i].onclick = function() {
        display.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    };
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Comment: atm `display` is an array of dom elements, to access and set you need something like `display[0].innerHTML = nKeys[i].innerHTML;`. this assumes theres only one element with a class of `'Screen'`

Comment: `display` is not an array. It is an `HTMLCollection` object, which is an array-like object. It has properties which are accessible via numerical indexes, and properties like `length`, but `HTMLCollection`s don't always have all of `Array`'s methods, and they are also [rather dangerously] "alive". See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving your display div an ID:

```
<div id="Screen"></div>
```

Then select it using `document.getElementById()`.

```
var display = document.getElementById('Screen');
```

Since you were using `document.getElementsByClassName()`, you were getting an HTMLCollection composed of (probably) 1 element. `getElementById()`, by contrast, only returns a single HTMLElement.

---

And since you say you're new to JavaScript, I would like to deter you from using "old school" event listeners like `onclick`. `HTMLElement.onclick` still *works*, but `HTMLElement.addEventListener()` is usually better because you can bind more than 1 listener to your elements.

```
var nKeys = document.getElementsByClassName('nButton');
var display = document.getElementById('Screen');

var length = nKeys.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  nKeys[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    display.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
  }, false);
}
```

Unfortunately, addEventListener isn't supported in IE8. If you need to support Grandma then use jQuery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var $nKeys = $('.nButton');
  var $display = $('#Screen');

  var length = $nKeys.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    $($nKeys[i]).on('click', function() {
      $display.html($(this).html());
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I've actually tried the ID version before, too.
HTML code: 
        <div id="Calculator">
            <div id="top">
                <span class="Clear">C</span>
                <div id="Screen"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rest">
                <span class="nButton">7</span>
                <span class="nButton">8</span>
                <span class="nButton">9</span>
                <span class="operator">+</span>
etc.
And yes, as I was saying I'm new to all of this. My only experience is some html/css basic stuff. Trying to educate myself! Sorry for lame ass questions.

Comment: Your question wasn't lame. You were really close. And I respect your self-education efforts. You should actually be proud that you need to ask questions, because that means that you are venturing into areas you aren't comfortable with and are learning new things. And that's one of the great things about programming. There are always new technologies emerging that are worth exploring.